# Cannot read directive value in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to implement a table that can read URL parameter from its `grid-url` directive. Later on, this one will be supplied to `$http` in the controller.
However it doesn't seem to work as expected. The value is always undefined.

Here's the markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped" grid-url="http://localhost/records/all">
  ...
</table>
```

Here's the relevant initialization snippet:

```
app.directive('gridUrl', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // Add the gridUrl property to the scope
            scope.gridUrl = attrs.gridUrl;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    // Expect to get http://localhost/records/all, but get undefined instead
    console.log($scope.gridUrl);
});
```

It doesn't look like as if it was the problem with the scope isolation. When invoking `console.log($scope)` in controller itself, the weirdest thing is that I can see the that `$scope.gridUrl` has `http://localhost/records/all`.

So what causes the property `gridUrl` to be undefined in controller?

Comment: maybe the controller function is called the directive. you can check with `$timeout(function() { console.log($scope.gridUrl); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to make it possible, while keeping the structure the same. The trick here is to use `$timeout` service with 10 milliseconds.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout(function(){
     // Getting http://localhost/records/all as expected
     console.log($scope.gridUrl);
  }, 10);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `gridUrl` in  controller, then bind it with your directive:

```html
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="$scope.gridUrlAttr = 'http://localhost/records/all'">
    <table class="table table-striped" grid-url-attr="$scope.gridUrlAttr">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
app.directive('gridUrl', function(){
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            gridUrlAttr: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // Add the gridUrl property to the scope
            console.log(scope.gridUrlAttr);
            // here you can change the gridUrlAttr value
        }
    }
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    // Expect to get http://localhost/records/all, but get undefined instead
    console.log($scope.gridUrlAttr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use service to share the data between modules:

```
    app.factory('SharedService', function() {
      return {
        sharedObject: {
          value: ''
        }
      };
    });`
```

Comment: Here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m?p=preview) i found.

Comment: So If I have 20 pages with tables, I gotta define `SharedService` for each one? Isn't simpler just to have a thing which is variadic, while the rest is shared? I.e the only thing that changes in each table is the URL itself, the rest stays the sane.

Answer (score 0):

It is defining controller first. So in the scope there is no property gridUrl. You have to use shared service to inject your directive into controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the controller is being invoked first, and then the directive is being compiled. So the gridUri value lands in the scope but few cycles after the controller invocation.

To prove that you can output this variable in your template:

```
<table class="table table-striped" grid-url="http://localhost/records/all">
  test :: {{ gridUrl }}
</table>
```

It will showup as well as the property in $scope after logging in to the console. (it updates in the console when it is an object)

Depending on what do you need the variable for, you can either put the watch on it to trigger some actions when it appear in the scope or you can redesign the way you provide the data (e.g. add some shared UI model service).